# Mounting a git repository in Salt's gitfs without it being searched for state modules

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to mount a repository with server config files (think nginx, mysql, etc) inside my salt fileserver in order to be able to distribute these files to my minions (Without having to do a checkout of the full repository on all my minions).

If I've understood correctly: All `gitfs_remotes` will be 'flattened' into one filesystem structure (I can confirm this when I run `salt-run fileserver.file_list`.

What worries me is that, as far as I know, this 'config file only' repository is now also being searched by Salt for state modules.

Is there some way to either:

- Designate a gitfs mount as 'don't search for SLS files'.
- Mount the actual salt state repository (which contains my `top.sls` and state modules) under a subdirectory of the salt fileserver and point salt to the `top.sls` therein?

I stand open to the possibility that this is a wrong approach entirely of course, my only requirement is that the server config files (again, nginx, mysql, etc) live in a separate repository, and that the entire high state (state modules, top file) lives in git.

master config:

```
    fileserver_backend:
      - gitfs
    gitfs_remotes:
      - git@github.com:MyOrg/salt-configs.git:
      - git@github.com:MyOrg/server-config-files.git:
        - mountpoint: config-files
```

Comment: What do you mean by "search"? It doesn't scan the fileserver and collect all the .sls files at any point. It simply fetches files by path when they're requested.

Comment: @OrangeDog I was under the impression that all folders where indeed being scanned to build some kind of index of available states. It seems this is not the case, so this voids my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered storing your configuration file in a pillar?

For example:

```
HostFiles:
  LinuxBasic: |
    192.168.1.1 server1
    192.168.1.2 server2
```

And then in your state file, when you want to render the hostfile:

```
LinuxBasicHostFile:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/hosts
    - contents_pillar: {{ HostFiles:LinuxBasic }}
```

You could also GPG that file if it was sensitive using the keys on your Salt master's server:

```
$ cat nginx.hostfile | sudo gpg --armor --batch --trust-model always --encrypt --homedir <salthomdir> -r <keyname>
```

Paste the output of that into your pillar:

```
HostFiles:
  LinuxBasic: |
    -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
    Xks383...a bunch of encrypted text...BjAs0
    -----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

And inform your salt master that HostFiles contains GPG encrypted content in your master.conf, or better yet, in a local conf file in /etc/salt/master.d/decrypt.conf:

```
decrypt_pillar:
  - 'HostFiles': gpg
```